# Reports -- how to do a comparison of two fields

Tags: reporting, formula, date

We have three date fields to be compared on a report. Lets say DateA, DateB and DateC.
The formula is when Date A is populated then do DateC- DateA else do DateC-DateB.

I understand we can create a formula field and use it in the report. However, this formula only needs to be evaluated for just one report so I wanted to calculate it directly on report (if possible) instead of creating a field.
I noticed that 'add formula' option is only available for a summary report and it seems that the formula is not evaluated on record level but just on summary level.
Please advice how can I do this calculation in a report at record level. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

user4435979 - unfortunately, you can not define formula fields on Reports in the tabular view - that is, they don't execute on a record level

The workaround is to define a new formula field on the Object itself (which I can see you would prefer not to do) but if you give the new field a label such as `RPT: Date Difference` then perhaps users won't be inclined to choose it in Views and other Report construction.

Another Workaround is to use an appexchange product like Conga Composer that will output directly to Excel and you can do the formula calculation in Excel rather than in the SFDC SObject

Comment: Great idea! Thanks for the answer. I added the field and will now prefix it with RPT. Thanks again 

Comment: yes - I use a variant of this for fields I prefix with `Admin:` if it is a field used solely by the sysad that doesn't appear on page layouts but certain profiles might see it in list views or reports